# Is there any difference between initializing a struct with {0} or {'\0'}?

Tags: c, struct, initialization

A work colleague recommended to initialize a struct with `{'\0'}` instead of `{0}` because he explained that`0` is considered to be an `int` thus at least 4 bytes. Therefore if a struct is not a multiple of 4 initializing the struct to `0` may leave some bytes not initialized to `0` while because `\0` is an ASCII char of size 1 byte it will initialize a struct to zero regardless of its size.

That being said I almost never saw initialization using `{'\0'}` while I did see lots of initializations using `{0}`.

My question is whether initializing a struct with `{0}` is enough? Is it enough because most compilers will automatically pad the bytes which are not multiple of 4 with zeroes or is it because C does it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no difference.

For one, `'\0'` is not "one byte"; in C, character constants have type `int`, so `'\0'` and `0` are 100% equivalent in every context. (You can check this with `sizeof`: Both `sizeof 0` and `sizeof '\0'` will yield the same value, typically 4 or 8.)

The other reason is explained in the initialization rules of C (in C99 that's *6.7.8 Initialization*):

> [...]
>
> 16. Otherwise, the initializer for an object that has aggregate or union type shall be a brace-enclosed list of initializers for the elements or named members.
> 17. Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated *current object*. When no
>       designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according
>       to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure
>       members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union. [...]

This says the members of the initialization list are used to initialize the fields of a struct or array in order; it doesn't matter how many bytes they have.

If you write

```
struct foo { double x; };
struct foo var = { 0 };
```

then `0` (the first initializer value, type `int`) is used to initialize the first struct field (`x`, type `double`). It's as if you had written `double x = 0`. The effect is that the value of `0` is implicitly converted from `int` to `double` and stored in the variable.

Furthermore, if there are fewer initializers than struct or array elements, this rule kicks in:

> 21. If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>       of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>       size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>       initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

So how does implicit initialization work with static objects?

> 10. If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>       indeterminate. If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly,
>       then:
>
>     - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>     - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>     - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
>     - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules.

This means all not-explicitly-initialized members of an array or struct are implicitly set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, initializing a struct with {0} is enough. Understand the compiler doesn't assign the memory to struct based on the initialization. A struct independent of whether it's filled with some value or not will always require the same memory.

e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A {
    char a;
};

struct B {
    int b;
};

int main(void) {
    struct A b = {'\0'};
    struct A c = {0};
    printf("%zu %zu\n",sizeof(b),sizeof(c));

    struct B ab = {'\0'};
    struct B ac = {0};
    printf("%zu %zu\n",sizeof(ab),sizeof(ac));

    return 0;
}
```

The answers will always be the same independent of how you assign it.